# My bluetooth not starting (No default controller available) in my ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, hp

I have ubuntu 22.04 installed in my HP laptop. My bluetooth sometimes gets turned off and after it does not start, even after I try to turn it on.

It shows a `Bluetooth turned off` screen and the toggle (on/off) button does not work.

I tried few solutions that I got on the internet like...

```
sudo rfkill block bluetooth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

This is my result

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-10-21 19:01:58 IST; 9min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 3939 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 27944)
     Memory: 652.0K
        CPU: 65ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─3939 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Oct 21 19:01:58 anupam-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-ec2xxx systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Oct 21 19:01:58 anupam-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-ec2xxx bluetoothd[3939]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Oct 21 19:01:58 anupam-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-ec2xxx systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Oct 21 19:01:58 anupam-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-ec2xxx bluetoothd[3939]: Starting SDP server
Oct 21 19:01:58 anupam-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-ec2xxx bluetoothd[3939]: Bluetooth management interface 1.2
```

But it still does not work.

I tried to do it manually with `bluetoothctl` but it says this

```
[~] sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

I also tried

```
[~] btmgmt power on
Set Powered for hci0 failed with status 0x14 (Permission Denied)
[~] sudo btmgmt power on
Set Powered for hci0 failed with status 0x11 (Invalid Index)
```

hciconfig:

```
[~] hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:3 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT
```

lsmod:

```
[~] lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth            1040384  16 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm 
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
```

rfkill:

```
[~] rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0     blocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

Later I tried this as well

```
modprobe -r btusb
modprobe -r btintel
modprobe usb
modprobe btintel
```

But it still shows the same

```
No default controller available
```

I then tried to `reboot` my system. It does show the controller for sometime but then again starts showing the same message:

```
[~] sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 50:C2:E8:35:84:78 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 6F:4E:59:69:AA:84 BB-113
Device 48:D8:45:E6:85:CD OPPO Enco Buds2
Device 41:42:CF:CC:38:72 Airdopes 393ANC
Device C8:9B:D7:D7:0E:BE realme 8i
[bluetooth]# connect 48:D8:45:E6:85:CD
Attempting to connect to 48:D8:45:E6:85:CD
[CHG] Controller 50:C2:E8:35:84:78 Class: 0x00000000
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-aborted-by-local
[CHG] Controller 50:C2:E8:35:84:78 Powered: no
[CHG] Controller 50:C2:E8:35:84:78 Discovering: no
[DEL] Device C8:9B:D7:D7:0E:BE realme 8i
[DEL] Device 41:42:CF:CC:38:72 Airdopes 393ANC
[DEL] Device 48:D8:45:E6:85:CD OPPO Enco Buds2
[DEL] Device 6F:4E:59:69:AA:84 BB-113
[DEL] Controller 50:C2:E8:35:84:78 anupam-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-ec2xxx [default]
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# exit
```